# Profile picture not copied to other profiles - needed for WinterBash

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I've added a custom Stack Overflow avatar (yes, to support the WinterBash hats better)... but I only see the picture on StackOverflow, not on Meta or Math.

How can this be?

I'm also missing the feature to reuse the uploaded picture.

[image][image]

Comment: Because you didn't choose to copy it to all profiles?

Comment: @Bart I *think* that if he doesn't change anything else, it won't let him save. (don't want to repro, got some different stuff I'd like to keep)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You've got a sock, haven't you?

Comment: My general profile has copied the latest profile... hm... need to figure out how to get it on this profile :P

Comment: @Antony you mean shadow, yeah... totally right!

Comment: @Bart, how do I copy it?

Comment: When you edit your profile, at the very bottom there is a button allowing you to save your profile and copy it to all accounts.

Comment: Yep, I just confirmed @Bart theory with my [loyal shadow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/206610/shadow-of-the-shadow). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, there is a button for that when you edit the profile:

[image]