# Change the profile picture for all sites without syncing the whole profile

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I'm looking for a functionality to upload a new profile picture and use it on all SE sites but keep individual information in each profile instead of [syncing the whole profile to all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211833/237803).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the time the question you linked was asked, the functionality [was changed a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239619/new-smarter-profile-creation-and-syncing).

Just go to your [profile editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), upload the picture you want and choose "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities". Only the changed part of profile would be synced -  the profile picture in your case.

[image: confirmation dialog showing that only the profile picture will be changed]