# The new profile editor (only on MSE currently) doesn't ask for confirmation before saving changes to all the accounts

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-interface

I realized it when I tested [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251702) to be sure it really works (you know, just in case) using the profile editor on MSE and then I had an edit suggested [showing the confirmation dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38098)... and then I remembered that the profile editor on MSE used to ask for confirmation to save the changes I made to all my SE accounts, before it [was updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features).

You can haz a pic of the appearance of this dialog by following the link to the suggested edit [I already mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/38098), but there is how it looked like on MSE in case you wonder (this is when you change your display name, but also applies to any changes, of course):

> [image]

But now it doesn't ask for any confirmation and just says that the changes have been saved once I click the (second in this case) button:

> [image]

Can I get the confirmation dialog back?

Comment: Alternatively, don't visit your profile page after you've been drinking.

Comment: Are you certain you want the confirmation dialog back? Yes - No

Comment: Socratic dialogues would be better.

Answer (score 3):

I personally do not feel that a *confirmation* is necessary. At the same time, I am not against adding it back. However, regardless of whether the confirmation returns or stays gone, I think that feedback about exactly *what* has changed *is* valuable, and that's the real value I saw in the old confirmation dialog. I think that feedback should remain.

So, if a confirmation dialog is brought back, I believe it should still say "This will update the following fields..."

However, if it remains as-is without the dialog, I think the successful save message should be modified to include e.g. "The following fields have been saved".

This information is important for clarity, I think, in a system where some of the fields may be saved across sites and others may remain unmodified.

---

(That said, given that the system works this way, the confirmation dialog has the benefit of letting users catch unintentional field changes that may overwrite unique values on all site profiles; a pain to undo if this wasn't the intent. On the other hand, this purpose could be equally well served by providing a visual indication of what fields were modified near the fields themselves. On the other other hand, I don't feel very passionate about this particular point... I just think it's worth noting that accidental operations when modifying all site profiles at once *are* difficult to undo.)